# c# regex for number/number/string pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find `{a number} / { a number } / {a string}` patterns. I can get `number / number` to work, but when I add `/ string` it does not.

Example of what I'm trying to find:

```
15/00969/FUL
```

My regex:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d/\d/\w");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `+` [quantifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that means `1 or more times` and it applies to the pattern preceding the quantifier, and I would add word boundaries `\b` to only match whole words:

```
\b\d+/\d+/\w+\b
```

C# code (using verbatim string literal so that we just could copy/paste regular expressions from testing tools or services without having to escape backslashes):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\b\d+/\d+/\w+\b");
```

If you want to precise the number of characters corresponding to some pattern, you can use `{}`s:

```
\b\d{2}/\d{5}/\w{3}\b
```

And, finally, if you have *only* letters in the *string*, you can use `\p{L}` (or `\p{Lu}` to only capture uppercase letters) shorthand class in C#:

```
\b\d{2}/\d{5}/\p{L}{3}\b
```

Sample code (also featuring [capturing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) introduced with unescaped `(` and `)`):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\b(\d{2})/(\d{5})/(\p{L}{3})\b");
var res = rx.Matches("15/00969/FUL").OfType<Match>()
                       .Select(p => new
                       {
                           first_number = p.Groups[1].Value,
                           second_number = p.Groups[2].Value,
                           the_string = p.Groups[3].Value
                       }).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+/\d+/\w+");
```

Complete example:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\w+)");

string input = "15/00969/FUL";
var m = r.Match(input);

if (m.Success)
{
    string a = m.Groups[1].Value;   // 15
    string b = m.Groups[2].Value;   // 00969
    string c = m.Groups[3].Value;   // FUL
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this answers the question within your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the quantifiers in your Regex

If you want to match 1 or more items you should use the `+`.
If you already know the number of items you need to match, you can specify it using `{x}` or `{x,y}` for a range (`x` and `y` being two numbers)

So your regex would become:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d/+\d+/\w+");
```

For example if all the elements you want to match have this format (`{2 digit}/{5 digit}/{3 letters}`), you could write:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d/{2}\d{5}/\w{3}");
```

And that would match `15/00969/FUL`

More info on the Regular Expressions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool match = new Regex(@"[\d]+[/][\d]+[/][\w]+").IsMatch("15/00969/FUL"); //true
```

Regular Expression:

```
[\d]+ //one or more digits
[\w]+ //one or more alphanumeric characters
[/]   // '/'-character
```